# Debug Django project with environment in docker container

Tags: python, django, debugging, docker

I am running Django project with environment in docker container OK, when i want to debug this project, pycharm run

> python2.7 -u /opt/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/pydevd.py –multiproc –qt-support –client 10.0.2.2 –port 56359 –file /opt/project/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
>
> no cython.... run "/usr/local/bin/python2.7" "/opt/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/setup_cython.py" build_ext –inplace

and stack...

using this advice https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-18913#comment=27-1373843
i connect manually pycharm_helpers volumes to docker container pycharm settings (see [temp2.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XIvi.jpg))

then manually run 
"/usr/local/bin/python2.7" "/opt/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/setup_cython.py" build_ext –inplace

setup_cython build successfully, 
commit image with installed cython inside, 
start debug again and see :

> python2.7 -u /opt/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/pydevd.py –multiproc –qt-support –client 10.0.2.2 –port 56359 –file /opt/project/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000

on debug console window
and stack on it again.....

i have fedora 21 and tried to systemctl disable firewalld and systemctl stop firewalld

> systemctl status firewalld
>
> firewalld.service - firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon
>   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/firewalld.service; disabled)
>   Active: inactive (dead)

but still have problem

FYI:

> ip link show dev docker0
>   4: docker0:  mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default 
>   link/ether 02:42:be:3a:42:eb brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
>
> iptables -L -n -t nat | grep DOCKER
>
> DOCKER     all  –  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE > match dst-type LOCAL
>
> DOCKER     all  –  0.0.0.0/0           !127.0.0.0/8          ADDRTYPE > match dst-type LOCAL

I tried to connect pycharm to docker container by ssh - debugging work fine.
But i want to solve the problem with docker interpreter

Comment: Debugging dockerized python with pycharm is notoriously bad. I gave up and installed an SSH server in the container and then configured the project to use a remote host - the containerized python